# Erlang gen_tcp missing packets?

Tags: tcp, erlang, imap, pop3

I'm developing a mail client adapter for Erlang. I'm having issues when I try to perform a fetch command, Erlang isn't able to get the body's content.

This is output from my terminal, when I'm trying to utilize the command through netcat:

```
4 FETCH 2 BODY[2]
* 2 FETCH (BODY[2] {1135}

                <div>
                    test content
                </div>
            )
4 OK FETCH completed.
```

The only output the gen_tcp server is able to receive is this binary:

```
<<"* 2 FETCH (BODY[2] {1135}\r\n">>
```

The source code is here:

```
-module(mailconnector).

-behaviour(gen_server).

-export([start_link/2, stop/0]).
-export([init/1, handle_call/3, handle_cast/2, handle_info/2, terminate/2, code_change/3]).

start_link(Host, imap) ->
    gen_server:start_link({local, ?MODULE}, ?MODULE, [Host, 143], []).

stop() ->
    gen_server:call(?MODULE, stop).

init([Host, Port]) ->
    {ok, Sock} = gen_tcp:connect(Host, Port, [binary, {packet, 0}, {active, true}]),
    {ok, {Sock, 0}}.

handle_call(stop, _From, State) ->
    {stop, normal, ok, State};

handle_call({login, Username, Password}, _From, State) ->
    {NewState, Output} = action(State, string:join(["LOGIN", Username, Password], " ")),
    case Output of
        {ok, Response, Data} -> Result = {Response, Data};
        _ -> Result = false
    end,
    {reply, Result, NewState};

handle_call(list, _From, State) ->
    {NewState, Resp} = action(State, "LIST \"\" \"*\""),
    {reply, Resp, NewState};

handle_call({select, MailBox}, _From, State) ->
    {NewState, Output} = action(State, string:join(["SELECT", MailBox], " ")),
    case Output of
        {ok, Response, Data} -> Result = {Response, Data};
        _ -> Result = false
    end,
    {reply, Result, NewState};

handle_call({fetch, Num}, _From, State) ->
    {NewState, Output} = action(State, string:join(["FETCH", Num, "BODY[1]"], " ")),
    case Output of
        {ok, Response, Data} -> Result = {Response, Data};
        _ -> Result = false
    end,
    {reply, Result, NewState};

handle_call(_Command, _From, _State) ->
    {reply, not_valid, _State}.

handle_cast(_Command, State) ->
    {noreply, State}.

handle_info(_Info, State) ->
    {noreply, State}.

terminate(_Reason, _State) ->
    ok.

code_change(_OldVsn, State, _Extra) ->
    {ok, State}.

action(_State = {Socket, Counter}, Command) ->
    NewCount = Counter+1,
    CounterAsList = lists:flatten(io_lib:format("~p ", [NewCount])),
    Message = list_to_binary(lists:concat([CounterAsList, Command, "\r\n"])),
    io:format("~p~n", [Message]),
    gen_tcp:send(Socket, Message),
    {{Socket, NewCount}, listener(Socket, NewCount)}.

listener(_Sock, Count) ->
    receive
    {_, _, Reply} ->
        io:format("RECEIVED: ~p~n", [Reply]),
        Messages = string:tokens(binary_to_list(Reply), "\r\n"),
        io:format("~p~n", [Messages]),
        find_message(Messages, Count)
    after 5000 ->
        timeout
    end.

process_message(Message, Count) ->
    StringCount = lists:flatten(io_lib:format("~p", [Count])),
    case [MCount|PureMessage] = string:tokens(Message, " ") of
        _M when StringCount == MCount ->
            {ok, string:join(PureMessage, " ")};
        _ -> [_Command|Output] = PureMessage, {data, string:join(Output, " ")}
    end.

find_message(Messages, Count) ->
    find_message(Messages, Count, []).

find_message([], _, _) ->
 false;    

find_message([H|T], Count, Data) ->
    case process_message(H, Count) of
        {ok, Message} -> {ok, Message, lists:reverse(Data)};
        {data, Output} -> find_message(T, Count, [Output|Data])
    end.
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: TCP is a stream protocol so here is no guarantee that you will receive the whole message in one go, even if it has been sent in that way. It is up to the receiving end to collect "enough" bytes for the whole message. In your case you only wait for one message. To be safe in `listener/2` I would match TCP messages with a `{tcp,Socket,Reply}` pattern, it is more explicit and safer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is just a comment and not an answer to your question which I believe rvirding provided above.

Since you are using one of the standard behaviours (gen_server) one would assume that you intend to write an OTP compliant application.  If so you should never use a receive expression directly unless you are prepared to handle all possible system messages as well as your application's.  In the case of a gen_server or gen_fsm non-system messages are processed by your handle_info/2 callback function.  You could use the State variable to hold an indicator of what command you were processing (e.g. login) and have a separate clause for each:

```
 handle_info({tcp,Socket,Reply}, #state{pending = login} = State) ->
 ...;
 handle_info({tcp,Socket,Reply}, #state{pending = list} = State) ->
 ...;
```

... however that would become a poor man's finite state machine so you'd be better off porting it to a gen_fsm behaviour callback module where you have a separate state for each (i.e. wait_for_login).  Then you can use handle_info/3:

```
 handle_info({tcp,Socket,Reply}, wait_for_login, State) ->
 ...;
 handle_info({tcp,Socket,Reply}, wait_for_list, State) ->
 ...;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are in `active` mode, the best approach consists in receiving the stream in your `handle_info` (or in your custom receiving function) using the pattern `{tcp, Socket, Msg}` and store it in a buffer until it does satisfy a specific pattern matching or it has a specific length, then you flush the buffer as you wish.

As @rvirding said you can't be sure that all your message will be received in a single packet, so you have to handle possible multiple packets. Otherwise you have to use `passive` mode and the function `gen_tcp:recv/2` but keep in mind that this function is blocking.

I suggest you to read this: http://learnyousomeerlang.com/buckets-of-sockets